# Java: Is it possible to Optimize double comparisons/multiplications?

Tags: java, optimization, double, mathematical-optimization, micro-optimization

I've been stuck on a very concerning problem with my physics engine, and it's that I'm having trouble calculating for thousands of Collisions all at once. I've optimized the method responsible for telling me collision so much, it creates 0 objects and is just multiplication/comparison at this point; yet it's still not fast enough!

*Note: Please don't rip me on physics engine structure, my project currently adds physics to Minecraft, a game made of literally millions of cubes. One could imagine that creates a couple unique challenges for such a simulation -.-

In context, a Polygon is an array of 8 vectors; and a Vector is just a vector... Also a dot product of 2 vectors is (v1.x*v2.x+v1.y*v2.y+v1.z*v2.z). Anyway, here's the code that uses 10% of all processing time at this point!

```
public class ReusableCollisionObject{

public boolean seperated;
public double movMaxFixMin,movMinFixMax;
private static double maxPlayer,minPlayer,maxBlock,minBlock,dot;

public void generateCollision(Polygon movable_,Polygon stationary,Vector axes){
    maxPlayer = minPlayer = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[0]);
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[1]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[2]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[3]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[4]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[5]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[6]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(movable_.vertices[7]);
    if(dot>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = dot;
    }

    maxBlock = minBlock = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[0]);
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[1]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[2]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[3]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[4]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[5]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[6]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    dot = axes.dot(stationary.vertices[7]);
    if(dot>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = dot;
    }
    if(dot<minBlock){
        minBlock = dot;
    }
    seperated = minPlayer>maxBlock||maxPlayer<minBlock;
}
```

}

Is it even possible to make raw math like this run faster?

Edit: Thanks to the answers I've gotten, I restructured the operations for performance and converted all the Doubles into Floats. Here's the new, much optimized class.

```
public class ReusableCollisionObject{

public boolean seperated;
public double movMaxFixMin,movMinFixMax;
private static double maxPlayer,minPlayer,maxBlock,minBlock;
private static final float[] cachemovable_ = new float[16];

public void generateCollision(Polygon movable_,Polygon stationary,Vector axes){
    cachemovable_[0] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[0].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[0].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[0].Z;
    cachemovable_[1] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[1].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[1].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[1].Z;
    cachemovable_[2] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[2].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[2].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[2].Z;
    cachemovable_[3] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[3].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[3].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[3].Z;
    cachemovable_[4] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[4].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[4].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[4].Z;
    cachemovable_[5] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[5].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[5].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[5].Z;
    cachemovable_[6] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[6].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[6].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[6].Z;
    cachemovable_[7] = axes.X*movable_.vertices[7].X+axes.Y*movable_.vertices[7].Y+axes.Z*movable_.vertices[7].Z;
    cachemovable_[8] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[0].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[0].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[0].Z;
    cachemovable_[9] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[1].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[1].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[1].Z;
    cachemovable_[10] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[2].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[2].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[2].Z;
    cachemovable_[11] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[3].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[3].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[3].Z;
    cachemovable_[12] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[4].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[4].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[4].Z;
    cachemovable_[13] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[5].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[5].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[5].Z;
    cachemovable_[14] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[6].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[6].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[6].Z;
    cachemovable_[15] = axes.X*stationary.vertices[7].X+axes.Y*stationary.vertices[7].Y+axes.Z*stationary.vertices[7].Z;

    maxPlayer = minPlayer = cachemovable_[0];
    maxBlock = minBlock = cachemovable_[8];

    if(cachemovable_[1]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[1];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[1]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[1];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[2]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[2];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[2]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[2];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[3]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[3];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[3]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[3];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[4]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[4];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[4]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[4];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[5]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[5];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[5]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[5];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[6]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[6];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[6]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[6];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[7]>maxPlayer){
        maxPlayer = cachemovable_[7];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[7]<minPlayer){
        minPlayer = cachemovable_[7];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[9]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[9];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[9]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[9];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[10]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[10];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[10]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[10];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[11]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[11];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[11]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[11];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[12]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[12];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[12]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[12];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[13]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[13];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[13]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[13];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[14]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock =  cachemovable_[14];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[14]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[14];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[15]>maxBlock){
        maxBlock = cachemovable_[15];
    }
    if(cachemovable_[15]<minBlock){
        minBlock = cachemovable_[15];
    }
    seperated = minPlayer>maxBlock||maxPlayer<minBlock;
}
```

}

Comment: What multiplications? The first thing is to get rid of all the calls to `axes.dot()`.

Comment: The dot product is of 2 Vectors is V1.X*V2.X + V1.Y*V2.Y + V1.Z*V2.Z

Comment: Of course it is, but there is no such calculation in the code you posted.

Comment: And an hour after saying so there still isn't. Clearly `Vector` isn't 'just a vector' at all, it is a class that exports a `dot()` method that calculates a dot product, that is called 16 times in the course of this method, and you still haven't posted it.

Comment: Are you sure this is faster than using a loop? Java support loop unrolling for you. Does every shape have exactly 8 vertices?

Comment: How CPU this uses depends on how often you call it. I would try calling it less often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you are calling the method as few times as possible - if that might not be the case, check Geoffrey De Smet's answer, and reduce the number of times you are calling it!  And if you think you are calling it as few times as possible, check his answer first, just in case!

Also, I am going to assume you are not using strictfp; if you are, don't.  You don't need IEEE 754 compliant floating point for this.  This is usually not default, but I wanted to mention it just in case.

Here are a few ways to reduce the cost of your floating point code that don't involve algorithm redesign (but will contribute far less than algorithm redesign, if that can be done):

First, pre-compute and save as many calculations as you can, since memory is usually more readily available than CPU; even parts of calculations can be saved in many cases.

Also, profile using float rather than double.  Float requires moving less memory, and since Java tends to build tree-like objects in memory that spread out too much, rather than flat objects that keep everything together in a tiny package that will fit in a CPU cache line, you can increase the amount of data that will fit in your CPU's cache by reducing the size of your data type.

Try to get the code to auto-vectorize across your eight computations, since modern CPUs can perform anywhere from 8 to 32 floating point computations at a time using SSE/SSE2/SSE3/AVX extensions, within the same time as one normal floating point computation using the old 80x87-compatible floating point architecture - if your Java JIT/JVM supports auto-vectorization, you will probably need to rewrite your code so your JIT/JVM recognizes that it can vectorize; if your JIT/JVM does not support auto-vectorization, consider using a third-party library that exposes block native vector operations and compute all of the dot products in one operation, load them into a list, and then use min/max to find the limits.

Comment: Thanks man! I changed all the doubles to floats, restructured the math for vectorization, and I stored all the dot products in 1 float[16] array which easily fits in the CPU cache. Needless to say the method is running much much faster! It's down from 10% time to .1% time :D

Answer (score 2):

**Call that method less.** That's going to give you a better bigO scalability gain than just making that method a bit faster. When the profiler says a method is slow, there are 2 ways to solve it: make it faster or call it less.

How?

Suppose you check collisions of `1000` objects. I presume your current code check every combination for a collisions, so about `500000` combinations (A-B, A-C, A-D, ..., B-C, B-D, ..., C-D, ...), so that many calls to that method.

What if you could know which combinations would never collide, in advance? In a 1 dimensional space, a `NavigableMap` (which is plain java) can help you with that. In a multi-dimensional space, you 'll need something like a [kd-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) (or just apply it to 1 dimension which would already be good gain).

For example, if we just look to 1 dimension, given an object A on location `137.4` (in that dimension) with a speed of `20.3`, it can end up anywhere between `117.1` and `157.7`. So let's put that lowest number in a map: `NavigableMap.put(117.1, A)`. Now, given a B that ends up anywhere between `50.4` and `70.4`, we can ask `navigableMap.floorMap(70.4, true)` which won't contain A (which had a key of `117.1`) nor any other element with a lowest number above `70.4`.

Comment: As Geoffrey says, you will *never* get it fast enough unless you use more clever data structures. For 3D collision detection, something like a spatial decomposition using an oct-tree can be an enormous help. Unless you can limit the number of comparisons by knowing which small subset of the objects could possibly collide, you will always be beaten by the numbers.